# Unable to scrape Google search result from React app: blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, web-scraping, httprequest

I'm trying to scrape some data from a google search following [this guide](https://medium.com/@darshankhandelwal12/how-to-scrape-google-organic-search-results-with-node-js-d3abe0274f40). Running the following in a simple Node.js script works:

```js
const axios = require("axios");

const getGymOperatingHours = async (search) =>
axios
    .get(`https://www.google.com/search?q=${search}&gl=sg&hl=en`, {
      headers: {
        "User-Agent":
        'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.64 Safari/537.36 Edg/101.0.1210.47',
      },
    })
    .then(({ data }) => {
      //process data
    });
});
```

However, doing the exact same thing in my React app yields some errors: (viewed on my Google Chrome browser)

> xhr.js:164 Refused to set unsafe header "User-Agent"

With and without trying to set the header also yields this error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://www.google.com/search?q=Ark%20Bloc&gl=sg&hl=en' from origin 'http://localho.st:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

However, certain URLs work fine, like this one:

```js
export const getGymOperatingHours = async (name: string) => {
  return (
    axios
      .get(`https://static.wixstatic.com/media/04ac92_ab3411c5de584541aa237c4cf2a82093~mv2.jpg/v1/fill/w_2880,h_1196,al_c,q_90,usm_0.66_1.00_0.01,enc_auto/04ac92_ab3411c5de584541aa237c4cf2a82093~mv2.jpg`)
      .then(({ data }) => {
        //process data
      })
  );
};
```

I tried using both `http://localhost:3000` and `http://localho.st:3000` as per [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10892392/7577786), but frankly I completely don't understand any of this to know what I'm doing.

Is this CORS thing something on Google's side (and most other sites I tried) that's blocking requests from domains named `localhost:3000`? Is setting `User-Agent` in the header supposed to be a workaround for this, in which case I should try to figure out how to set the header?

Comment: yes its on google's side. you'll have to use their api...

Comment: @DanielA.White why does it work from my Node.js script though? And what API are you referring to?

Comment: because node isn't a browser. cors primarily affects browsers. google has a search api

Comment: use nodejs middleware to perform this task, browser localhost:XXXX will work.